# Weird display of results from search

Tags: bug, design

The results from [this search](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=wlog) don't seem to display properly. I'm assuming that it is not restricted to this search alone.

**Added later:** I have included a screenshot below. What I'm referring to is the display of the number of votes in the second and third entries.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what isn't displaying correctly?  Keep in mind that search has changed a great deal with SE 1.0, it displays questions and answers in the result list now.

Comment: I have included a screenshot and explanation.

Comment: Ah the cut off number blocks, gotcha. We'll get a fix out in just a bit.

Comment: @NickCraver, this bug seems still to be present, at least for me. Seems like an easy issue with css. Is there any plan to fix it?

Comment: @NickCraver: Would you be able to provide an update on this?

Comment: @NickCraver it seems 6-8 weeks should be enough to fix this design issue, but the bug is still there until now ;)